# Force Qt to "reset" its rendering engine

Tags: linux, qt, opengl-es-2.0, qt5, framebuffer

I'm not sure the question title is the best in the world, so I'll explain, of course.

We have a Qt5 application running on an embedded Linux system without X. It's using eglfs to render the GUI. We would like to be able to change the display resolution without terminating our application if at all possible.

Currently, I'm able to accomplish the resolution change with the following process:

1. Terminate the Qt5 application.
2. Use `fbset` to change the display resolution and timing information.
3. Unload and reload the kernel modules that provide the graphics driver. This is necessary because the driver doesn't seem to pick up the changes made by `fbset` in step 2. (I'm currently investigating how to avoid this).
4. Re-launch the Qt5 application.

If we can assume that I can solve the problem of having to reload the graphic driver kernel modules, is it possible to tell Qt to re-query the framebuffer and do whatever is necessary to adapt itself to the new resolution without restarting the application?

Some specifics:

- AM3358 SoC (ARM core)
- Linux kernel 3.12.10-ti2013.12.01 from TI
- The graphics drivers for the PowerVR SGX core are TI's graphics SDK 05.01.01.01
- Qt version is 5.3.1